# duplicating rows of a dataframe in new vector

Tags: r

I have a one column of data initiated like this:

```
Initcol <- data.frame(colnames(blocA))
```

Which results in this

```
1 AUSc1
2 AUSc2
3 AUSc3
4 AUSc4
5 AUSc5
6 AUSc6
7 AUSc7
8 AUSc8
9 AUSc9
10 AUSc10
```

And I would like to create a new data frame like this:

```
1 AUSc1
2 AUSc1
3 AUSc1
4 AUSc2
5 AUSc2
```

basically repeating each time line i x times.

I tried this:

```
col <- as.data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=3*10,ncol=1))
for (i in 1:3) {
  idx = floor(i/10)
  col[idx,] <- Initcol$colnames.blocA.[idx,]
}
```

But I got the error

> Error in `[.default`(Initcol$colnames.blocA., idx, ) :    incorrect
>   number of dimensions

So how can I get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

I think `unlist(lapply())` should do the job.

```
v <- 1:10
v2 <- unlist(lapply(v, rep, 3))
v2
```